# iOS Facebook SDK Native Sharing

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I have integrated Facebook Sharing of a link with a description, caption, etc via the Native Facebook App (if it is installed) using the code:

```
FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] initWithLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://abcde.com"]
                                                                       name:@"demo"
                                                                    caption:@"demo"
                                                                description:@"demo"
                                                                    picture:nil];

         //Present share dialog
        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                          if(error) {
                                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                              NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                          } else {
                                              // Success
                                              NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                          }
                                      }];
```

When this method runs, and the native facebook app is installed, I get an option to share a post that has caption, link and description. When I click share and I go on FB to check it, it appears to only have the link?

Can someone suggest a possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to newest [Facebook sharing policy 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill)